# sanitizeHtml failed to work, all other normal texts are removed unexpectly

Tags: html-sanitizing

I need to transform the `<e>` tag to `<a>` tag, and keep everything else escaped rather than removed.

However sanitize-html not only failed to process the self closing `<e>` tag, it also killed the `<?php` part.

I created a minimal case to test:

```
yarn add sanitize-html@1.27.5
```

And main.js:

```
let sanitizeHTML = require('sanitize-html')
let rawHtml = `
<e type="mention" title="@user1" />

How to output phpinfo:

<?php
phpinfo();
?>

test
`
const clean = sanitizeHTML(rawHtml, {
  allowedTags: ['a', 'e', 'span'],
  disallowedTagsMode: 'escape',
  selfClosing: ['e'],
  transformTags: {
    'e': function(tagName, attribs) {
      if (attribs['type'] == 'web') {
        return {
          tagName: 'a',
          attribs
        }
      } else {
        return {
          tagName: 'span',
          attribs,
          text: attribs['title']
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

console.log(clean)
```

I expect the output to be:

```
<span>@user1</span>

How to output phpinfo:

<?php
phpinfo();
?>

test
```

But instead it was this (the <?php tag and the "test" string is removed)

```
<span>@user1</span>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?